# Unable to resolve 415.378: missing requirement [415.378] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.lowagie.text)

Tags: spring, maven

> Error: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in
>   bundle userportal-impl [415]: Unable to resolve 415.378: missing
>   requirement [415.378] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=com.lowagie.text)

I'm able to build the project successfully but not able to run.

I'm using karaf-3.0.0 and jdk 1.7.0_101

I'm getting the this error when I'm trying to use itext pdf jar. I'he tried various versions of iText as 7.0, 5.5, 1.4.8, etc But the error continues as it is.. Please help me to solve this error. I've referred various links on stackoverflow

[Karaf / Maven - Unable to resolve: missing requirement osgi.wiring.package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480508/karaf-maven-unable-to-resolve-missing-requirement-osgi-wiring-package)

[OSGi: Missing requirement osgi.wiring.package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757837/osgi-missing-requirement-osgi-wiring-package)

but still I'm not able to solve this error.

===================== pom.xml =========================

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>com.monitor.app</groupId>
<artifactId>app-services</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.monitor.app.userportal</groupId>
<artifactId>userportal-impl</artifactId>
<name>userportal-impl</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<cxf.version>2.7.5</cxf.version>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<bundle.import.package>
com.hub.platform.commons,
com.hub.platform.logging.api,
com.hub.platform.services.api,
com.hub.platform.utils,
com.hub.platform.rdbms.api,
javax.sql,
javax.ws.rs,
javax.xml.bind.annotation,
org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs,
org.codehaus.jackson,
org.codehaus.jackson.map,
org.codehaus.jackson.node,
org.springframework.dao,
org.springframework.jdbc.core,
org.springframework.jdbc.support,
com.hub.platform.notification.api,
com.hub.platform.crypto.api,
javax.ws.rs.core,
</bundle.import.package>
<bundle.export.package>com.monitor.app.userportal.api</bundle.export.package>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.hub.platform.services</groupId>
<artifactId>services-api</artifactId>
<version>${hub.services.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.hub.platform.rdbms</groupId>
<artifactId>rdbms-api</artifactId>
<version>${hub.rdbms.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.hub.platform.crypto</groupId>
<artifactId>crypto-api</artifactId>
<version>${hub.crypto.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.hub.platform.notification</groupId>
<artifactId>notification-api</artifactId>
<version>${hub.notification.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- 
<dependency>
<groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
<artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
<version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
<artifactId>io</artifactId>
<version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
<artifactId>layout</artifactId>
<version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
<artifactId>forms</artifactId>
<version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
<artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
<version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
<artifactId>pdftest</artifactId>
<version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>1.7.18</version>
</dependency>
-->

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
<artifactId>itext</artifactId>
<version>1.4.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>1.7.18</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.7</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>bundle</id>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>bundle</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<instructions>
<Bundle-Name>SM User/Patient Impl</Bundle-Name>
<Bundle-Description>This bundle is used for getting all user/patient portal related service</Bundle-Description>
<Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
<Import-Package>${bundle.import.package}</Import-Package>
<Export-Package>${bundle.export.package}</Export-Package>
</instructions>

</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: shutdown `xxxIDE` delete `.m2` folder (maven repositories) , Restart `IDE>force update>clean install` if that doesn't works then something is wrong with your code

Comment: Hello Tome, Thanks for helping. But this is not working for me. The maven is able to download the required dependency in .m2 folder, There is no compilation error. I'm not able to understand this why it is giving the error like this? Is there any problem with versions?